# c++ solution to locking a directory - linux

Tags: c++, linux

A simple question. Is it possible to lock a directory under linux ? Actually what I need is that only one application (which I wrote) has an access to a specified directory which is created by this application. So basically it is a cache directory for that app and so-far users have been messing with it. so i wish to prevent this in future.

Is it possible to do this?? and how  (language: c++)?

Comment: You mean *cache*, right?

Comment: Short answer is no, you can't prevent a directory from being used by a normal application and not let the user see/know it's there. Depending on exactly what it is you want to prevent the user from doing, there may be a few different solutions (hashing content, running with privileges [note, doesn't stop people with root access from "messing" with the cache], etc)

Comment: they can see it,  no problem, but the as long as they don't mess with it : edit files, write lock them, change their names and the name of the directory itself

Comment: Can you describe why and how users end up *messing with application files*?  That sounds unusual since nearly every program, to some degree, uses files that users are not expected to mess with.

Comment: The way to do something like this is with set-uid or set-gid. Make the directory only writable by the owner/group of the application. The application then uses set-uid or set-gid to switch to that owner or group when it needs to modify the cache files.

Comment: If your cache file contain critical information (like license ending date, user premium type etc.. ) you need to encode your file. The content should not be human readable.

Comment: Maybe you can use this? http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/01/linux-unshare-m-for-per-process-private.html
IIRC, there is a C wrapper function `unshare` for the underlying system call.

Comment: @CagkanToptas That won't prevent them from messing with the files if they have write permission.

Comment: well these are regular text files. divided according to  certain key which happens to be interesting tosome people. so they made this hack to exploit these files and write into then while my app is running. I have no problem with this as long as i am not responsible for the final outcome. but recently i become responsible for it. since my as* is on the line i am trying to protect it. so it is either this or encoding everything.

Comment: @Barmar maybe I'm wrong but as I know you can access any file using admin rights (with sudo or using suid()) so the idea here is making content not human readable so that users cannot change the content for their benefit. Of course it is possible that a user can delete some of content and corrupt the file but in that case I would ignore it in my program and form a new cache file.

Comment: @CagkanToptas I think he's just worried about ordinary users, there's not much you can do about admins unless you're using something like SELinux. But you're essentially saying that instead of trying to prevent users from destroying the files, you should just live with it and work around it.

Comment: A long long time ago, a file / directory was not removed until there were no links to it and no processes had it open.  So it was possible to create a file, open the file, and delete the file, and still use the open file descriptor.  Directories have changed since they had 14 char and 2 byte inode number, so this may not work any more.

Comment: If you set the directory permissions to +x-r then they can not use ls(1) to see what files are in the directory.  They can not mess with what they can not see.  If they know the file names, then they can still open the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible in standard C++ at all.

Under linux, use setuid permissions on the executable, so it runs in context of its owner.    Then you can lock down access permissions for the directory, so it is only accessible to the owner of the executable.

Of course, this doesn't stop users using your program from messing with your cache.   You need to design your program so it prevents inappropriate actions by users.   And make sure the owner account (which can be set up specifically for your application) does not have more privileges than it needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust people who have "root" permission on the system(s) that this is installed on, you can rely on having a special user or group, and use `setuid` and/or `setgid` to prevent others from tampering with the file. This does, however, mean that the installer of the software will need to have root permission, so "any" user can't install the software, which in some circumstances may not be a good solution.

The better solution is really to either have a hash of the file stored in the file [plus some constant data or some such, so that the user can't just run `sha1 modified-file` and get the "right hash"], or encrypt the whole file.

The problem with BOTH of these methods is that you still can't rely on it 100% - someone with enough motivation and resources will figure out what the constant data is, and just calculate that as new hash after modifying the data in your file. And similarly, assuming your application knows how to decrypt the file, the application can be reverse engineered to find the encryption key and encryption method.

So you are fighting a "code war" (pun on cold war) against your "users".

There are commercial solutions available for license management (and that I have been the user of is FlexLM, but there are several others too). This is a little more work, and will probably cost a little bit in license fees, but you will save yourself a whole heap of potential headache if you use a commercial product.

Comment: If you can't trust privileged users on a system, you probably can't trust unprivileged users either, and you wouldn't want "any" user installing the software anyway.      License management is only one form of this problem - enforcing user compliance with license restrictions.  The other aspect, which has little if anything to do with licensing, is reducing the chances of a user accidentally or deliberately messing with data and affecting how the program run.   The latter is not a code war - it is simply constraining program use so a quality of service can be achieved.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that it's not unusual for systems to allow root access to the local machine (through `sudo` for example) - and thus the regular user would be able to access any file anyway. Both my current and my previous place of work, I and all my colleagues have root access - to allow easy installation of new versions of software without having to wait for someone in the IT department to get involved.